# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. Trying to make a simple timer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a simple timer which run till a given time. This is how I have tried to call the timer function. It gives the error as mentioned in the title. I believe the error is there because I am calling set state method in the init state, but I really need to make this functionality that, when this widget enters the screen, a timer begins and do something when the timer ends. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
late double timeRemaining;
  late Timer _timer;
  void startTimer(double timeRemaing) {}

  @override
  void initState() {
    timeRemaining =
        widget.startDate.difference(widget.endDate).inSeconds / 1000 - 80;
    const Duration seconds = Duration(seconds: 1);

    _timer = Timer.periodic(seconds, (timer) {
      
      setState(() {
        timeRemaining--;
        if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
          // done = true;
          done = true;
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

as the title says, you're building widget during another build (when you call `setState` in the timer).So the solution is to wait for the widget to finish building, then start your timer, this can be done by using [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), like the following:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    timeRemaining =
        widget.startDate.difference(widget.endDate).inSeconds / 1000 - 80;
    const Duration seconds = Duration(seconds: 1);

    // this will schedule a callback for the end of this frame.    

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _timer = Timer.periodic(seconds, (timer) {
      
      setState(() {
        timeRemaining--;
        if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
          // done = true;
          done = true;
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
      });
    

    super.initState();
  }
```

try it and tell me if this works

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. But the issue still remains. when the timer is done ticking this error props up. Before that even my implementation works perfectly. What Should I do

Comment: I think I found the solution. It was something else that was breaking my code. Thank you so much for your help.